# jQuery $.each variable Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a scope issue problem with a `$.each` loop in **jQuery**.  How can I get a global variable in a function to set in a loop or at least pass something out of it?

```
var some_function = function() {

    // false by default
    var something = false;

    $.each(array, function(key, val) { 
       if (val == 'something')
       {
         // even if one item evaluates true I need to check outside of the loop
         something = true;
       }
    });

    if (something == true)
    {
       // do something else, but always false
    }
}
```

Since I'm needing to evaluate all items in the array, and **if only one is** `true`, then do something additional, outside of the `$.each`.

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    something(); 
    $(':radio').trigger('change');
)};
```

Ok, so this is the actual code.  It's alerting **'false'** at the bottom and then alerts **'hello'** twice, as if it's going in reverse order.

```
var something = function() {   

        var q_radios = {
            'radio1'        : 'radio1_selector', 
            'radio2'        : 'radio2_selector',  
        };
        var show_me = false;

        $.each(q_radios, function(name, q_selector) {  
            $('input:radio[name=' + q_selector + ']').change(function() {  
                    show_me = true; 
                    alert('hello'); 
            }); 
        });   

        if (show_me == true)
        {
            alert('yes');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('false');
        }

};
```

Comment: Did you try it? It should work fine as it is.

Comment: Sure have, fails everytime. Though I am feeling a bit retarded today.

Comment: @wes When in doubt, jsFiddle it.

Comment: working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/101/

Comment: @wes Then `val` never equals `'something'`. Can you post what `array` is?

Comment: Are you ever calling `some_function()` ??? http://jsfiddle.net/PC4Vq/

Comment: Works fine; http://jsfiddle.net/LPnEV/

Comment: Ok, that is extremely odd because my code does match, an alert proves it.  Mind you this function is being called in document.ready but is all defined outside of it's scope.  Would that cause this craziness?

Comment: What is your actual `if` condition? I'm guessing you're not really doing `if (val == 'something')`

Comment: I'm iterating over checkboxes to see if one is checked. Though I've bypassed it to evaluate to true everytime, for testing purposes.

Comment: You should include a code snippet from your actual code as what you've included above works correctly.

Comment: Please post what you're actually doing.

Comment: Does you array is `checkbox`s onbject i.e `$(':checkbox')` or something like that?

Comment: yeah, if you're passing a jQuery selector array match, the value for each index will never be "something", it'll be an object. if you're passing a true array of values (not jQuery selecting), then your problem doesn't make sense. did you ever try alerting each val?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you really mean "only one", or do you mean "at least one"? Someone bolded that text for you. Not sure if that's what you intended.

Comment: Your code is running correctly. The invocation of `something()` assigns the event handlers to the radio buttons, but does not *trigger* the handlers. The alerts in those handlers will only fire when the event occurs. Then after that, you get the `'false'` alert at the bottom. Now the `something()` function is done, and the `$(':radio').trigger('change');` line runs, which triggers the handlers that were assigned when `something()` ran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More or less, exactly what you have now … you just need to pass the data into the function (by letting it accept an argument). See [a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hf3A8/2/).

```
var some_function = function(array) { 

    // false by default
    var something = false;
    $.each(array, function(key, val) {
        if (val == 'something') {
            something = true;
        }
    });

    if (something == true) {
        alert("There was a something");
    } else {
        alert("There wasn't a something");
    }
};

some_function([1,2,3]);
some_function([1,"something",3]);
​
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend native Array iteration methods:

```
var something = array.some(function ( val ) {
   return val === 'something';
});
```

Here, `something` will be `true` if at least one array element has the value `'something'`.

Comment: This won't test if "only one" of the items meets the condition, but I have a feeling that's not what OP actually wants. If not, then `.some()` is a good approach, as long as there are no other side effects that need to be applied beyond the first match. Otherwise, `.reduce()` could be used, or `.map` with `.length`.

Comment: Nice, but what if it's a object ?

Comment: @DestyNova An array-like object? Could you give an example?

Comment: Just like in the question: {'radio1': obj1, 'radio2':  obj2, ... }.

an other lil question: for arrays and array-like objects, how to iterate copies and not direct reference to the real items ?

Comment: @DestyNova There’s a new `.values()` method which gives you an array of property values, e.g. `obj.values() // returns [obj1, obj2, ...]`, but you’d need to check which Babel presets implement it. You can also go `Object.keys(obj).some(key => { let val = obj[key]; /* check val like above */ })`. As for the second question, you’d have to create the copies first. If the objects are DOM nodes, you’d need to clone them, but cloning DOM nodes manually isn’t very common, I think.

Comment: Thx for reply, so for object I'll stay with `$.each()` since I suppose that `.values()` will create a new array instance (while `.each()` seems to be a light iterator). And for deep cloning object, I found `.clone()` in jQuery for DOM object and `jQuery.extend()` for JS object.